# Terminal emulator integrated with qt/any other GUI Framework

Tags: terminal, desktop-application, terminal-emulator

I want to make a terminal emulator similar with Warp Dev for Mac. I basically just want a window in the pyqt application that has a emulated or native terminal from the os and other views for a login/register/AI Chat for terminal help/file upload to cloud. Do you think this is a feasible project? I want to know where to start on the client side, i dont know if qt is a good option either for this. I want to make it as simple as possible, like integrating an emulated terminal would be a better idea but i dont know hot to do it. Can you give some advice?

I tried searching the web for answers but there are not many related topics on this and i didnt find a very good path.

Answer (score -1):

VTE is a terminal emulation library for the GTK widget. It is used by GNOME Terminal, GNOME Console, Terminator, Tilix and a whole lot more. It's very easy to embed this widget in your GTK application.

I *think* Konsole, Yakuake and Cool Retro Term have a similar common widget behind them, using the QT toolkit, but I'm not entirely certain about it, I leave it to you to gather more info about it.